# Interrupted formatting a partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-format

I had a 20TB LUN in one of my systems named `maptha`. I created two 10TB partitions out of it, `mapathap1` and `mpathap2`.

When I ran the command

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/mapper/mpathap1
```

another completely different and non-related system IO got slow so I had to stop formatting immediately because the second system was really important. Is the partition damaged? How may I find out if it is damaged or I can rely on it?

Comment: It's probably not damaged, but since the filesystem was not allowed to be created properly it's probably unusable until you let `mkfs` run to completion.

Comment: is there any command, log or utility that i can use to check partition or lun status? or run a test?

Comment: Utilities that deal with file systems should have no reason to write to the partition table. Nor they write *outside* the partition you specify when you invoke them. Your partition should be safe, and commands like `sudo fdisk -l /dev/mapper/mpathap1` or `sudo parted /dev/mapper/mpathap1 print` should tell you if something is not ok.

Answer (score 1):

Does your device support S.M.A.R.T.? If so, you can take a look if there were any errors at hardware level (this may not be partition-specific). As was pointed out above, terminating the process of filesystem creation should not cause any damage, and you can restart it. Once `mkfs` finishes, you can check the available filesystem with `e2fsck`.